# Elastic search, node.js, mongosastic

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

by default mongosastic uses pluralization of mongodb collection as index name to index records .. how to make it index collection without pluralization ?

for ex - our mongodb collection i have given as mydb but it searches for mydbs then only it index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want pluralization, you can pass the collection name by one of the below ways:-

1) Creating the schema

```
var schema = new Schema({ name: String }, { collection: 'user' });
```

2) Set the collection name

```
schema.set('collection', 'user');
```

3) While creating the model

```
var collectionName = 'user'
var M = mongoose.model('User', schema, collectionName)
```

You should have the index created for **"user"**.

```
http://localhost:9200/user
```

Comment: var M = mongoose.model('User', schema, collectionName)
 
what is 'User' here ?

Comment: User is the singular name of the collection. If there is no third parameter, mongoose by default will look for the plural form of user. As we have given the third parameter as collection name "user", it means mongoose dont use pluralism and it just uses "user".

Comment: Do u have any documentation regarding how to communicate to elastic search using node.js like for search queries and updating or deleting docs ? ... thanks in advance